# How is a statistic represented as a mapping with varying sample size?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, notation

Suppose there is a sample of varying size $n\in \mathbb N$, each sample point taking values in $\mathbb R$, and a statistic $T$. If I am correct, a statistic can accept arbitrary sample size. What are some standard ways to represent/write the statistic $T$ with varying sample size $n$?  For example,

1. We may write the statistic $T$ as a mapping from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$ for each different $n$
   value.  How can we make sure that, the different mappings for
   different $n$ values are from the same statistic $T$ not from
   another different one?
2. Can we write $T$ as a single mapping for all $n$ values? How is the statistic $T$ represented as a mapping with varying number of arguments (here arguments are sample points in the sample) then?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of *sufficient statistics*?

Comment: yes, I know it. @whuber

Comment: In your terminology, a set of sufficient statistics typically is a map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^d$ for a *fixed* $d$ (equal to the number of sufficient statistics) and $T$ can be written as the composition of that with a *fixed* map from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The problem of varying $n$ disappears.

Comment: @whuber: $T$ as the composition will still be a mapping from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$, isn't it? The dimension $n$ of its domain still depends on the sample size.

Comment: But that doesn't matter. What question of *statistical* interest are you really trying to ask?  There seems to be no content or motivation to this question, which appears to be purely about mathematical notation.